# async support in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, restful-url

I am building an web application that can support asynchronous functionality in spring mvc.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestRestful</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**restful-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <!--  It scans a package and all of its subpackages, looking for classes that could be automatically registered 
              as beans(@Component, @Controller, @Repository and @Service) in the Spring container. -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="education.controller" />
        <!-- Maps request to controller and controller methods that are annotated with @RequestMapping -->
        <!-- useDefaultSuffixPattern="false"
            Set whether to register paths using the default suffix pattern as well: i.e. whether "/users" should be registered as "/users.*" too.
            Default is "true". Turn this convention off if you intend to interpret your @RequestMapping paths strictly.
            Note that paths which include a ".xxx" suffix already will not be transformed using the default suffix pattern in any case.
        -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"  
            p:order="1"
            p:useDefaultSuffixPattern="false"/>


        <task:annotation-driven/>
</beans:beans>
```

**HelloRestController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Callable<String> testmessage(){

        return new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {

                return "hello rest";            
            }
        };

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="test1/{email}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String testemail(@PathVariable("email") String email){
        System.err.println("plain email method->"+email);

        return "test plain email";
    }
}
```

On calling test1/{email}, I am getting correct return.

But, on calling test, I am getting HTTP Status 406 ERROR CODE.

Also found during debug my code is not even goes to call method.

Kindly advice...

Comment: Use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`  and not the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`.

Comment: Adding mvc:annotation-driven solves the problem,but new problem occurred that email entering in path variable is truncated... like abc@gmail.com becomes abc@gmail

Comment: Add a `BeanPostProcessor` which finds the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and set the `useDefaultSuffixPattern` to `false`. You could also try to put everything that `<mvc:annotation-driven />` does in XML but that is far more work then adding a `BeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: 'PathVariable' doesn't work when you expect to have dots in the input. Use a 'RequestParam' instead.